# Latency of shuffle instructions in CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

About the latency of `__shfl()` instruction:

Does the following instruction

```
c=__shfl(c, indi);

/*
where indi is any integer number(may be random (<32)), 
and is different for different LaneID.
*/
```

has the same latency comparing to, lets say:

```
c=__shfl_down(c,1);
```

Answer (score 4):

All warp-shuffle instructions have the [same performance](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#arithmetic-instructions).

Answer (score 4):

To provide a "quantitative" follow-up answer to Robert's answer, let us consider Mark Harris' reduction approach using CUDA shuffle operations detailed at [Faster Parallel Reductions on Kepler](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/faster-parallel-reductions-kepler/).

In this approach, warp reduction is performed by using `__shfl_down`. An alternative approach to warp reduction is using `__shfl_xor` according to [Lecture 4: warp shufﬂes, and reduction / scan operations](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/gilesm/cuda/lecs/lec4.pdf). Below, I'm reporting the full code implementing both the approaches. If tested on a Kepler K20c, both take `0.044ms` to reduce an array of `N=200000` `float` elements. Relevantly, both the approaches outperform Thrust `reduce` by two orders of magnitude since the execution time for the Thrust case is `1.06ms` for the same test.

Here is the full code:

```
#include <thrust\device_vector.h>

#define warpSize 32

/***********************************************/
/* warpReduceSum PERFORMING REDUCTION PER WARP */
/***********************************************/
__forceinline__ __device__ float warpReduceSum(float val) {

    for (int offset = warpSize/2; offset > 0; offset /= 2) val += __shfl_down(val, offset);
    //for (int i=1; i<warpSize; i*=2) val += __shfl_xor(val, i);    
    return val;

}

/*************************************************/
/* blockReduceSum PERFORMING REDUCTION PER BLOCK */
/*************************************************/
__forceinline__ __device__ float blockReduceSum(float val) {

    // --- The shared memory is appointed to contain the warp reduction results. It is understood that the maximum number of threads per block will be
    //     1024, so that there will be at most 32 warps per each block.
    static __shared__ float shared[32]; 

    int lane    = threadIdx.x % warpSize;   // Thread index within the warp
    int wid     = threadIdx.x / warpSize;   // Warp ID

    // --- Performing warp reduction. Only the threads with 0 index within the warp have the "val" value set with the warp reduction result
    val = warpReduceSum(val);     

    // --- Only the threads with 0 index within the warp write the warp result to shared memory
    if (lane==0) shared[wid]=val;   // Write reduced value to shared memory

    // --- Wait for all warp reductions
    __syncthreads();              

    // --- There will be at most 1024 threads within a block and at most 1024 blocks within a grid. The partial sum is read from shared memory only 
    //     the corresponding warp existed, otherwise the partial sum is set to zero.
    val = (threadIdx.x < blockDim.x / warpSize) ? shared[lane] : 0;

    // --- The first warp performs the final partial warp summation. 
    if (wid==0) val = warpReduceSum(val); 

    return val;
}

/********************/
/* REDUCTION KERNEL */
/********************/
__global__ void deviceReduceKernel(float *in, float* out, int N) {

    float sum = 0.f;

    // --- Reduce multiple elements per thread.
    for (int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; i < N; i += blockDim.x * gridDim.x) sum += in[i];

    sum = blockReduceSum(sum);

    if (threadIdx.x==0) out[blockIdx.x]=sum;
}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
void main() {

    const int N = 200000;

    thrust::host_vector<float> h_out(N,0.f);

    thrust::device_vector<float> d_in(N,3.f);
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_out(N);

    int threads = 512;
    int blocks = min((N + threads - 1) / threads, 1024);

    float time;
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);

    // --- Performs the block reduction. It returns an output vector containig the block reductions as elements
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
    deviceReduceKernel<<<blocks, threads>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_in.data()), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_out.data()), N);
    // --- Performs a second block reduction with only one block. The input is an array of all 0's, except the first elements which are the
    //     block reduction results of the previous step.
    deviceReduceKernel<<<1, 1024>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_out.data()), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_out.data()), blocks);
    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    printf("CUDA Shuffle - elapsed time:  %3.5f ms \n", time);      
    h_out = d_out;

    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
    float sum = thrust::reduce(d_in.begin(),d_in.end(),0.f,thrust::plus<float>());
    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    printf("CUDA Thrust - elapsed time:  %3.5f ms \n", time);       

    printf("Shuffle result = %f\n",h_out[0]);
    printf("Thrust result = %f\n",sum);

    getchar();

}
```